# Comprimir un archivo

Tags: c#

Estoy generando un log, pero al momento de querer comprimir la carpeta esta se cae ya que el programa sigue ejecutando el log.

lo que tengo es lo siguiente:

```
dateTime = DateTime.Now;
string nombrearchivo = "log_" + dateTime.ToLongTimeString().Replace(":", " ") + ".txt";
string carpeta = @"E:\log\"+dateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
        
if (!Directory.Exists(carpeta))
{
    sw = new StreamWriter(@"E:\log\" + Directory.CreateDirectory(carpeta) + @"\" + nombrearchivo, true);
    string starpath = carpeta;
    string zipPath = carpeta + ".zip";

    ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(starpath, zipPath);
}
else
{
    sw = new StreamWriter(@"E:\log\" + Directory.CreateDirectory(carpeta) + @"\" + nombrearchivo, true);
}
```

Mientras se genera el zip, pero este se cae al momento de ejecutarse, ya que el zip no puede tener acceso a la carpeta porque está siendo utilizado.

agradezco cualquier ayuda.

Comment: ¿Es necesario que comprimas la carpeta entera? Si un archivo está abierto puedes comprimir los que no, en lugar de la carpeta completa.

Comment: si necesito comprimir la carpeta completa, ya que luego debo enviarla por correo

Comment: respuesta rapida... cerra ese archivo!!!!!

Comment: Está cerrado mas abajo, ya que es un log

Comment: sw.WriteLine("**FIN SERVICIO");
                sw.Close();

Comment: Tienes que cerrar antes de llamar a ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory()  sino te seguirá diciendo que está siendo utilizado.